# Comparing VALUE and REFERENCE of types

Tags: c#, types, comparison, equals, equals-operator

I know there are a lot of ways to compare VALUE and REFERENCES in C#, but I'm still a bit confused about what type performs what when you try to compare either VALUE or REFERENCE.

String examples:

```
string str = "hello";
string str2 = "hello";

if (str == str2)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Something");
} // Is this a comparison of value?

if (str.Equals(str2))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Something");
} // Is this a comparison of value?

string.ReferenceEquals(str, str2); // Comparison of reference (True)

Console.WriteLine((object)str1 == (object)str2); // Comparison of reference (True)
```

Comment: I believe strings are a particular case: when the compiler sees two times the same string, it makes only one in memory. So value OR reference doesn't matter in this case.

Comment: The string class overloads operator==(), Equals and GetHashCode.  Makes it act like a value type.

Comment: string are a special kind of reference type. Better use something else (StringBuilder) to study this.

Comment: @Baboon: right conclusion, wrong reasoning. Two strings at different locations with the same content will be equal.

Comment: That's what i meant, it will always return true, whether you compare value or reference.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Equals` and `==` will compare by reference by default if they're not overriden / overloaded in a subclass. `ReferenceEquals` will always compare by reference.

Strings are a confusing data type to use for experimenting with this, because they overload `==` to implement value equality; also, since they're immutable, C# will generally reuse the same instance for the same literal string. In your code, `str` and `str2` will be the same object.

Comment: `==` is needs to be overloaded, not overridden.

Answer (score 2):

@Inerdia is right with what he says but I'd like to point out the reason why the line string.ReferenceEquals(str, str2) returns true in your code example.  Because you are defining both of the strings at compile time, the compiler can optimise the code so they can both point to the same instance of the string.  Since strings are immutable the compiler knows it can do this even though String is a reference type.  But If you change your code to dynamically generate one of the strings (as shown below) the compiler can't perform this optimisation.  So in your code example if you change your code to:

```
string str = "hello";
string str2 = new StringBuilder().Append("he").Append("llo").ToString();
```

Then the string.ReferenceEquals(str, str2) line will now return false as this time the compiler cant know to re-use the same instance (reference of the string).

Answer (score 2):

### Equality and Comparision of ReferenceTypes and strings:

Reference types work like this:

```
System.Object a = new System.Object();
System.Object b = new System.Object();
a == b;      //returns true
a.Equals(b); //returns false

b = a;
a == b;      //returns true
a.Equals(b); //returns true
```

Since strings are Reference types they should do the same, shouldn't they? **But they don't!**

C# Documentation defines string equality like this:

> Although string is a reference type, the equality operators (== and
>   !=) are defined to compare the values of string objects, not
>   references (7.9.7 String equality operators). This makes testing for
>   string equality more intuitive.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/362314fe%28v=vs.71%29.aspx
>   https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa664728%28v=vs.71%29.aspx

This has implications for you test code.

```
if (str == str2)
{
   Console.WriteLine("Something");
} // This is comparision of value even though string is a referenceType

if (str.Equals(str2))
{
   Console.WriteLine("Something");
} // This is comparison by value too, because Equals is overrided in String class.
```

Keep in mind you as a programmer (Or your tricky coworker) can override .Equals(), changing it's behaviour, what you see above is what should happen. It's not necessarily in line with your codebase-reality, when in doubt check out the definition by marking .Equals() and hitting F12.

### Addendum for x.Equals

The behavior of object.Equals() *should* these rules:

> - List item
> - x.Equals(x) returns true.
> - x.Equals(y) returns the same value as y.Equals(x).
> - if (x.Equals(y) && y.Equals(z)) returns true, then x.Equals(z) returns true.
> - Successive invocations of x.Equals(y) return the same value as long as the objects referenced by x and y are not modified.
> - x.Equals(null) returns false.
>     https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms173147%28v=vs.80%29.aspx

Whenever you are in doubt you can call x.ReferenceEquals, it's defined as following:

> Unlike the Object.Equals(Object) method and the equality operator, the
>   Object.ReferenceEquals(Object) method cannot be overridden. Because of
>   this, if you want to test two object references for equality and you
>   are unsure about the implementation of the Equals method, you can call
>   the method.
>
> https://msdn.microsoft.com/de-de/library/system.object.referenceequals%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Thus:

```
System.Object a = new System.Object();
System.Object b = a;
System.Object.ReferenceEquals(a, b);  //returns true
```

In your example the compiler merges your strings in optimization thus:

```
string str = "hello";
string str2 = "hello";
string.ReferenceEquals(str, str2); // Comparison of reference (True)
```

This behaviour is only duo to compiler optimization in your example, if we randomize the code it will return false:

```
string str = "hello";
string str2 = "hello";
if(throwCoin)
{ 
   str2 = "bye";
}   
string.ReferenceEquals(str, str2); // Comparison of reference (False)
```

Answer (score 1):

1. string.ReferenceEquals(str, str2);
    
   It obviously compares references.
2. str.Equals(str2) 
   Tries to compare references at first. Then it tries to compare by value.
3. str == str2
   Does the same as Equals.

A good way to compare strings is to use string.Compare. If you want to ignore case, there is a parameter in place for that too.

Answer (score 0):

Excerpt from .net sources:

```
public bool Equals(string value)
{
  if (this == null)
    throw new NullReferenceException();
  else if (value == null)
    return false;
  else if (object.ReferenceEquals((object) this, (object) value))
    return true;
  else
    return string.EqualsHelper(this, value);
}
```

So in general it is comparision of references first and if they don't match, it compares values.

Comment: Which doesn't explain why `ReferenceEquals()` returns `true` too.

Comment: I'm wondering myself, if there is any case, when ReferenceEquals returns false and EqualsHelper returns true. If there is no such case, in case strings are not equal, Equals method is wasting time trying to compare symbol by symbol.

Comment: Sure there is. Any time you create two strings with the same text and at least one of them is not interned. E.g. `var s1 = new string(' ', 1); var s2 = new string(' ', 1);`. Generally, the only interned strings are those that are compile-time constants.