# C# String/string: Compare string like in Java (by Reference)

Tags: java, c#, string, reference

How do I compare strings by reference like in Java? I know C#'s strings are compared by value with `==`.

`Object.ReferenceEquals` does not work well too because C# assigns the existing address of a string to a new string if its contents already exist within the intern pool.

I've read this post and they suggest this:

[Comparing VALUE and REFERENCE of types](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7821416/comparing-value-and-reference-of-types)

```
string str = "hello";
string str2 = new StringBuilder().Append("he").Append("llo").ToString();
```

What I want to happen is something to this effect:

```
string s1 = "a";
string s2 = "a";
Console.WriteLine(s1 == s2); //False
//Or
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2)); //False
```

**However**, this is not the case for the 2 strings above. How do I achieve the same effect without using a `StringBuilder`?

Comment: What's wrong with `StringBuilder`?

Comment: If you really want your code to do this (and you're not merely experimenting), I'd suggest there is something seriously wrong with your design.  The end result will be hard to comprehend, and I believe it will be harder to maintain without breaking something.  If you really want to model a concept in which two objects could be different even if the string value is the same, define a class with a sequential ID number as a second field, or something similar.

Comment: I'm trying to create filler text for the TexBox such as "Type Here". I want to see if the "Type Here" has the same reference with my string so I differentiate when the user intentionally inputs "Type Here". This way, I do not treat the user string as filler text. @ajb

Comment: I hope you understand that relying on completely non documented behavior is quite questionable idea (and I doubt you even get the behavior you hope for as there is a good chance text obtained from Windows text box is always copied to new string...)

Comment: Agree completely with Alexei; trying to compare references is definitely not the right way to accomplish what you're trying to accomplish.  You have no idea whether the TexBox class retains the `string` you filled into the box, or even whether the class keeps the string as a `string` at all.  It could break it into objects that contain individual characters along with coordinates, or something.  I think what you want to do is add a keyboard listener so that you can tell whether the user typed anything in.  The best UI would be to immediately clear "Type Here" as soon as they enter any data.

Comment: I'd call this a good example of an [XY problem](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1):

You can use [`String.Copy`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.string.copy(v=vs.110).aspx) to create a new instance:

```
string s1 = "a";
string s2 = String.Copy(s1);
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s1,s2)); //False
```

Comment: Note that this in no way going to help OP to achieve detection of user input to match ghost text...

Answer (score 0):

You could simply use `new`:

```
char[] charArray = new char[3];
charArray[0] = 'a';
charArray[1] = 'b';
charArray[2] = 'c';

string s1 = new string(charArray);
string s2 = new string(charArray);
Console.WriteLine(Object.ReferenceEquals(s1, s2));
```

Runnable example: https://ideone.com/H1O16q

The reason this works is because `new` always creates a new instance of the given type without doing any internalization. Every major OOP language behaves this way, as far as I'm aware.

Answer (score -2):

In C# , string is immutable reference type. so, it has similar behaviors as value type (Ex: as your example here).  But string builder is purely reference type.

So, you cannot use string to compare reference, but you can use stringbuilder.

```
StringBuilder p = new StringBuilder("test");
        StringBuilder q = new StringBuilder("test");

        Console.WriteLine(p == q); //false
```

Comment: There is absolutely no relation between type being immutable and behaving like a value... And it is perfectly fine to compare strings as references (if there some particular reason for it - which don't seem to be the case of this question so).

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov I have never seen a good reason to compare strings as references.  Maybe someone will surprise me someday with a use case where it is the best approach.  But I doubt it.

Comment: @AlexeiLevenkov  in programmers point of view, string shouldn't be compare as reference. 99% of time, we need string as value and it should be able to compare easily. I'm totally agree with  ajb.

Comment: @hirannuwanga the fact that in most cases you don't need to compare strings by reference does not make you answer correct - neither "string is immutable type so has behavior similar to value type" nor "cannot use string to compare reference" is true.